# iOS - Using Twitter Reverse auth in app which doesn't use ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, twitter

I have an application which doesn't use ARC. Now I want to integrate twitter framework to get access token on authentication in my application. I just received my reverse auth enabled app. I was trying out this example - https://github.com/seancook/TWiOS5ReverseAuthExample
which works fine but when I try to integrate it with my project, it gives me bunch of memory issues and BAD_ACCESSes obviously because the code ARC enabled. Is there any way I can use it in my app ?

Thanks and any tip would be much appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one thing you can do is just add ***-fno-objc-arc*** to the included non-ARC supported file
for that  just go to the project building phase just as shown in illustration
[image]

and then just click on the file you want to put the compiler flag above just as shown in illustration

[image]

just put flag in popup window

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I have put up that flag on the files but still somehow its giving me crash.I'll post if I find the solution here.